# Depression in central peak of real part of diffusing Gaussian

Tags: schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, simulations

I'm attempting to use Crank-Nicolson scheme to solve the TDSE in 1D. The initial wave is a real Gaussian that has been normalised. As the solution evolves, a depression grows in the central peak of the real part of the wave, and the imaginary part's central trough is perhaps a bit higher than I expect (image below).

Does this behaviour seem reasonable? I have searched around and not seen questions/figures that are similar.
I'm happy to give more information, for example my code, or the matrices used in the scheme, etc. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Here's a link to GIF of time evolution:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdva6.jpg

And a link to my code:

https://github.com/kieranwhite82/python-computational-physics/blob/1b759791b921b9b836c99596f1a49372e559071c/CN_Schroedinger.py

Hopefully the setup behind my method is apparent enough in the comments of the code, if not I can provide clarification!

Comment: Have you tried doing a gif and seeing it's time evolution, to see if it makes sense? Also if you add, the concrete equation you are solving, it sure won't hurt :)

Comment: @guiablo Sorry for the long wait time, this is something I do in my free time. I've got a GIF and code for perusal! Appreciate any help.